# AngularJS Unable to repeat asynchronous function inside of service

Tags: angularjs, loops, asynchronous, service

I am building a form that can send and clear cached JSON data using AngularJS to a RESTful web service. When I click submit, the current form data is cached in a JSON object, I then send that data through the web service. Once it is sent I clear the cache.

I have a function I wish to use in multiple controllers (sending cached data). It loops through the cache, sending each JSON object one at a time. When I have the function in a single controller, the code works fine. But once I wrap it in a service and call it in through a controller, my loop no longer works. It runs fine if there is only 1 cache object. But if there are more than 1, the "this.sendCache()" will not fire. I believe this has something to do with the asynchronous function and am not sure what to do about it. Help is greatly appreciated!!!

Controller

```
app.controller('FormCtrl', function($scope, $filter, $window, getData, Post, randomString, $cordovaProgress, $cordovaDialogs, scService) {

    $scope.submitEntry = function() {

        var frmData = new Post($scope.postData);
        var postCount = window.localStorage.getItem("localPostCount");
        postCount ++;

        window.localStorage.setItem("localPostCount", postCount);
        window.localStorage.setItem("post" + postCount, JSON.stringify(frmData));

        scService.sendCache();

    };

});
```

Service

```
app.service('scService', function ($window, Post, $cordovaProgress, $cordovaDialogs, $timeout) {

    this.sendCache = function () {
        if(window.Connection){
            if(navigator.connection.type != Connection.NONE) {

                var postCount = window.localStorage.getItem("localPostCount");
                var curCacheObj = new Post(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("post" + postCount) || '{}'));

                if (postCount > 0) {
                    curCacheObj.$save().then(function(response) {
                        var servResponse = JSON.stringify(response);
                            if (servResponse.indexOf("@xmlns:ns3") > -1) {
                                console.log("Post " + postCount + " sent!");
                            }
                            else {
                                console.log("Unable to post at this time!");
                            }
                        }).then(function() {
                            window.localStorage.removeItem("post" + postCount);
                            postCount --;
                            window.localStorage.setItem("localPostCount", postCount);
                        }).then(function() {
                            console.log(postCount); //log shows 1
                            if (postCount > 0) {
                                    this.sendCache(); //yet this won't fire again!
                                }
                                else {
                                    $cordovaDialogs.alert('Submission recorded successfully', 'Success', 'OK').then(function() {
                                      console.log('Submission Success');
                                      $window.location.href= 'index.html';
                                    });
                                }
                    });
                }
                else {
                $cordovaDialogs.alert('Submission recorded successfully', 'Success', 'OK').then(function() {
                  console.log('Submission Success');
                  $window.location.href= 'index.html';
                });
                }
            }
            else {
                $cordovaDialogs.alert('Your current connection is too slow. Sync at a later time by returning to the app with a better connection.', 'Submission Stored', 'OK').then(function() {
                  console.log('Submission Cached');
                  $window.location.href= 'index.html';
                });
            }
        }
    };

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually a very common JS issue, and not related to AngularJS itself. `this` is not what you think it is. Inside the `.then()` callback, your context has changed so it is no longer pointing to your service but to the response context from the async call. Therefore, the function `sendCache()` does not actually exist and cannot be called that way.

All you need to do is take a reference to `self` at the top of your service:

```
var self = this;
```

Then use `self` instead of `this` in your call:

```
self.sendCache();
```

Note that this is not causing trouble for you with variables like postCount because they're locally defined within the closure and do not require `this` to be referenced. But if you were to define `this.postCount` or other variables in your service, you would need to do the same thing.

Comment: OMG IT WORKS I LOVE YOU! Seriously though, I would never have figured that out on my own

Comment: Don't feel bad. I knew the answer because I've done exactly the same thing, LOL.